# How can i copy value of my php variable to user's clipboard

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, clipboard

i have tried this one to copy my uploaded image to user's clipborad but image is uploading and its adress is showing after its uploading but i need to copy its adress to the user's clipboard too  `

```
<?php
//upload.php
if($_FILES["file"]["name"] != '')
{
 $test = explode('.', $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
 $ext = end($test);
 $name = rand(100, 999) . '.' . $ext;
 $location = './upload/' . $name; 
 $url= 'http://i.com/upload/' . $name;


 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $location);
 echo '<img src="'.$location.'" height="150" width="225" class="img-thumbnail" />';



 echo "\n\n\n\n$url";



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click on the button to copy the text from the text field. Try to paste the text </p>

<input type="text" value="$url" id="myInput">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>

<script>      function myFunction() 
{
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
}
?>
`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    let inputEl = document.getElementById("myInput");
    inputEl.select();                                    // Select element
    inputEl.setSelectionRange(0, inputEl.value.length); // select from 0 to element length

    const successful = document.execCommand('copy');   // copy input value, and store success if needed

    if(successful) {
        alert("Copied the text: " + inputEl.value);
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
</script>
```

**Edit:** To clarify and fix some other small errors:

```
<?php
    //upload.php
    if($_FILES["file"]["name"] != '')
    {
        $test = explode('.', $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $ext = end($test);
        $name = rand(100, 999) . '.' . $ext;
        $location = './upload/' . $name; 
        $url= 'http://i.com/upload/' . $name;

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $location);
        echo '<img src="'.$location.'" height="150" width="225" class="img-thumbnail" />';

        echo "\n\n\n\n$url";
    } else {
        $url = "";
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>example title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Click on the button to copy the text from the text field. Try to paste the text </p>

    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $url; ?>" id="myInput">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        let inputEl = document.getElementById("myInput");
        inputEl.select();                                    // Select element
        inputEl.setSelectionRange(0, inputEl.value.length); // select from 0 to element length

        const successful = document.execCommand('copy');   // copy input value, and store success if needed

        if(successful) {
            alert("Copied the text: " + inputEl.value);
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where to add this one

Comment: @Animesh I edited to include the script tags and function. The code belongs inside the function `myFunction()`.

Comment: @ ivan86 okhh  i'm cheking it  too i tried your previous code frnd

Comment: @Animesh No problem, let me know if it works (I'm 99.9% sure that it will).

Comment: its also not working  i have tried by adding your script tooo but now its not even uploading my img

Comment: can u tell me where i have to add your code with mine

Comment: try writing `inputEl.select();` instead of `inputEl.focus();`

Comment: Add the code right under the button `<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>`, replacing the old `<script></script>` and the code inside

Comment: 86 is thr any way if i remove html page from this ............. ????

Comment: @Animesh Oh, also, inside your input field, replace `<input type="text" value="$url" id="myInput">` with `<input type="text" value="<?php echo $url; ?>" id="myInput">`

Comment: @Animesh you html document is also missing a head section, which shouldn't be the reason for the error, but just to let you know, this is the proper minimal HTML format: [https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

Comment: @Animesh Your PHP needs to have closing tags before the doctype or you need an echo

Comment: @Animesh Here, I'll make the changes inside your code, then just copy paste

Comment: @Animesh Ok, try now. Just copy and paste the whole edit to replace all your code

Comment: thnx my frnd now it is working well and be safe  be in  home  okhh take care